# Installing from EPEL on Amazon EC2

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, fail2ban, epel

I am trying to install fail2ban on our Amazon EC2 Linux AMI (CentOS). I know that fail2ban is in the EPEL so I have done the following:

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh epel-release*rpm
```

However, when I do that I get the following message:

```
package epel-release-6-8.9.amzn1.noarch (which is newer than epel-release-6-8.noarch) is already installed
```

Which implies to me that EPEL is already available but if I do:

```
sudo yum install fail2ban
```

I get:

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, security, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates                                                                                | 2.3 kB     00:00
Setting up Install Process
No package fail2ban available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I assume that I am misunderstanding something but how can I install from EPEL?

EDIT: I have just done the following and found that the repo is not enabled:

```
yum repolist all
```

SO how do I enable a repo on EC2?

Comment: OK so I am not allowed to answer my own question yet but solved it with:
    yum-config-manager --enable epel

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should check that epel is enabled using

```
yum repolist enabled
```

If it's not then you can edit /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo and change the `[epel]` section

```
enabled=0
```

to

```
enabled=1
```

---

or use

```
 yum-config-manager --enable epel
```

Comment: OMG I LOVE YOU SO MUCH.

Comment: @yellottyellott I too, share mutual love for this random Internet stranger.

Answer (score 6):

Update for Amazon Linux 2:

```
sudo yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

Or,

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
```

Or,

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras enable epel
sudo yum install -y epel-release
```

Comment: That works great for Amazon Linux 2!

Answer (score 4):

The epel repo is on the default Amazon server but in not enabled by default. You can use it to install a package:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo epel install fail2ban
```